# How to extract specific parts from the array element that contains HTML code and create a new array with this extracted content?

Tags: php, html, arrays, string, associative-array

I've an array of comments titled `$comments`. The actual array could be huge in size, it may contain hundreds of such elements. For your understanding I've added only **10** elements to it as follows :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [text] => Second Comment Added                
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [text] => This is the long comment added to check thwe size of the comment on the device,if the size is more then add the hyperlink button to go on to the next page
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [text] => This comment is of two lines need to check more about it                
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [text] => This comment is of two lines need to check more                
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [text] => Uploading Photo  for comment <div title="comment_attach_image">

<a title="" title="colorbox" href="https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/CnYTVQdATAOQTkMxpAq4" ><img src="https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/CnYTVQdATAOQTkMxpAq4" height="150px" width="150px" /></a>

<a href="https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/CnYTVQdATAOQTkMxpAq4" class="comment_attach_image_link_dwl">Download</a>

</div>                
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [text] => test                
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [text] => Amit&#039;s pic<div class="comment_attach_image">
            <a class="group1 cboxElement" href="http://52.1.47.143/file/attachment/2015/03/e55f0f3080eb9828270a7963648a5826.jpeg" ><img src="http://52.1.47.143/file/attachment/2015/03/e55f0f3080eb9828270a7963648a5826.jpeg" height="150px" width="150px" /></a>

            <a class="comment_attach_image_link_dwl"  href="http://52.1.47.143/feed/download/year_2015/month_03/file_e55f0f3080eb9828270a7963648a5826.jpeg" >Download</a>
            </div>
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [text] => PDF file added<div class="comment_attach_file">
            <a class="comment_attach_file_link" href="http://52.1.47.143/feed/download/year_2015/month_03/file_1b87d4420c693f2bbdf738cbf2457d89.pdf" >1b87d4420c693f2bbdf738cbf2457d89.pdf</a>

            <a class="comment_attach_file_link_dwl"  href="http://52.1.47.143/feed/download/year_2015/month_03/file_1b87d4420c693f2bbdf738cbf2457d89.pdf" >Download</a>
            </div>                
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [text] => Just did it...                
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [text] => Profile photo uploaded<div class="comment_attach_image">
            <a class="group1 cboxElement" href="http://52.1.47.143/file/attachment/2015/03/a4ea5532b83a56bbbae2fffc80de4fee.png" ><img src="http://52.1.47.143/file/attachment/2015/03/a4ea5532b83a56bbbae2fffc80de4fee.png" height="150px" width="150px" /></a>

            <a class="comment_attach_image_link_dwl"  href="http://52.1.47.143/feed/download/year_2015/month_03/file_a4ea5532b83a56bbbae2fffc80de4fee.png" >Download</a>
            </div>                
        )

)
```

Now what I want to achieve is identify the type of comment based on the value contained in a key `[text]` of above array.

Let me explain you with the help of example. Let's consider about folowing one element `$comments[9][text]`

It contains following value(i.e. HTML code) :

```
Profile photo uploaded<div class="comment_attach_image">
                <a class="group1 cboxElement" href="http://52.1.47.143/file/attachment/2015/03/a4ea5532b83a56bbbae2fffc80de4fee.png" ><img src="http://52.1.47.143/file/attachment/2015/03/a4ea5532b83a56bbbae2fffc80de4fee.png" height="150px" width="150px" /></a>

                <a class="comment_attach_image_link_dwl"  href="http://52.1.47.143/feed/download/year_2015/month_03/file_a4ea5532b83a56bbbae2fffc80de4fee.png" >Download</a>
                </div>
```

First thing I want to extract from this HTML data is the end string from the string `<div class="comment_attach_image">`.

In other words I want to extract the word **image** from the string `<div class="comment_attach_image">`. This will indicate that this comment is of type **image**.

Then I want only the URL of image i.e.`http://52.1.47.143/file/attachment/2015/03/a4ea5532b83a56bbbae2fffc80de4fee.png`(value of src attribute of `<img>`).

Now both these values should be inserted into a new array with keys type and URL as follows :

```
Array
    (
        [9] => Array
            (
                [type] => image                
                [URL] => http://52.1.47.143/file/attachment/2015/03/a4ea5532b83a56bbbae2fffc80de4fee.png
                [text] =>             
            )
    )
```

Same thing should happen with another array element `$comments[7][text]` which is not of type image but of type file as follows :

It contains following value(i.e. HTML code) :

```
PDF file added<div class="comment_attach_file">
        <a class="comment_attach_file_link" href="http://52.1.47.143/feed/download/year_2015/month_03/file_1b87d4420c693f2bbdf738cbf2457d89.pdf" >1b87d4420c693f2bbdf738cbf2457d89.pdf</a>

        <a class="comment_attach_file_link_dwl"  href="http://52.1.47.143/feed/download/year_2015/month_03/file_1b87d4420c693f2bbdf738cbf2457d89.pdf" >Download</a>
        </div>
```

First thing I want to extract from this HTML data is the end string from the string `<div class="comment_attach_file">`.

In other words I want to extract the word **file** from the string `<div class="comment_attach_file">`. This will indicate that this comment is of type **file**.

Then I want only the URL of file i.e.`http://52.1.47.143/feed/download/year_2015/month_03/file_1b87d4420c693f2bbdf738cbf2457d89.pdf`(value of hre attribute of `<a>`).

Now both these values should be inserted into a new array with keys type and URL as follows :

```
Array
    (
        [9] => Array
            (
                [type] => file                
                [URL] => http://52.1.47.143/feed/download/year_2015/month_03/file_1b87d4420c693f2bbdf738cbf2457d89.pdf 
                [text] =>                
            )
    )
```

For other elements which doesn't contain any HTML i.e. containing simple text nothing should happen. For them the entry in new array should be like below :

Let's consider element `$comments[0][text]`

It contains following value :

```
Second Comment Added
```

So the entry in a new array should be as follows :

```
 Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [type] => text                
                    [URL] =>  
                    [text] => Second Comment Added             
                )
        )
```

In this manner the new array containing the comment type and it's content should get generate in an efficient way.

Can someone please help me in this regard?

If you have any doubt regarding the issue I'm facing please do let me know.

Any kind of help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Waiting for your precious replies.

The final desired array should be as follows :

```
Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [type] => text                
                    [URL] => 
                    [text] => Second Comment Added             
                )
        [1] => Array
                (
                    [type] => text                
                    [URL] => 
                    [text] => This is the long comment added to check thwe size of the comment on the device,if the size is more then add the hyperlink button to go on to the next page             
                )

         [2] => Array
                (
                    [type] => text                
                    [URL] => 
                    [text] => This comment is of two lines need to check more about it             
                )

          [4] => Array
                (
                    [type] => image                
                    [URL] => https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/CnYTVQdATAOQTkMxpAq4
                    [text] => Uploading Photo  for comment              
                )
[5] => Array
                (
                    [type] => text                
                    [URL] => 
                    [text] => test             
                )

[6] => Array
        (
            [type] => image                
            [type] => text
                    [URL] => http://52.1.47.143/file/attachment/2015/03/e55f0f3080eb9828270a7963648a5826.jpeg
                    [text] => Amit's pic
        )
[7] => Array
            (
                [type] => file                
                [URL] => http://52.1.47.143/feed/download/year_2015/month_03/file_1b87d4420c693f2bbdf738cbf2457d89.pdf 
                [text] =>                
            )
[8] => Array
                (
                    [type] => text                
                    [URL] => 
                    [text] => Just did it...            
                )
[9] => Array
            (
                [type] => image                
                [URL] => http://52.1.47.143/file/attachment/2015/03/a4ea5532b83a56bbbae2fffc80de4fee.png
                [text] =>  PDF file added           
            )       
        )
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$comments = array(
array(
    'text' => 'Second Comment Added'
),
array(
    'text' => 'This is the long comment added to check thwe size of the comment on the device,if the size is more then add the hyperlink button to go on to the next page'
),
array(
    'text' => 'This comment is of two lines need to check more about it'
),
array(
    'text' => 'This comment is of two lines need to check more '
),
array(
    'text' => 'Uploading Photo  for comment <div title="comment_attach_image"><a title="" title="colorbox" href="https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/CnYTVQdATAOQTkMxpAq4" ><img src="https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/CnYTVQdATAOQTkMxpAq4" height="150px" width="150px" /></a><a href="https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/CnYTVQdATAOQTkMxpAq4" class="comment_attach_image_link_dwl">Download</a></div>'
),
array(
    'text' => 'test'
),
array(
    'text' => 'Amit&#039;s pic<div class="comment_attach_image"><a class="group1 cboxElement" href="http://52.1.47.143/file/attachment/2015/03/e55f0f3080eb9828270a7963648a5826.jpeg" ><img src="http://52.1.47.143/file/attachment/2015/03/e55f0f3080eb9828270a7963648a5826.jpeg" height="150px" width="150px" /></a><a class="comment_attach_image_link_dwl"  href="http://52.1.47.143/feed/download/year_2015/month_03/file_e55f0f3080eb9828270a7963648a5826.jpeg" >Download</a></div>'
),  
array(
    'text' => 'PDF file added<div class="comment_attach_file"><a class="comment_attach_file_link" href="http://52.1.47.143/feed/download/year_2015/month_03/file_1b87d4420c693f2bbdf738cbf2457d89.pdf" >1b87d4420c693f2bbdf738cbf2457d89.pdf</a><a class="comment_attach_file_link_dwl"  href="http://52.1.47.143/feed/download/year_2015/month_03/file_1b87d4420c693f2bbdf738cbf2457d89.pdf" >Download</a></div>'
),
array(
    'text' => 'Just did it...'
),
array(
    'text' => 'Profile photo uploaded<div class="comment_attach_image"><a class="group1 cboxElement" href="http://52.1.47.143/file/attachment/2015/03/a4ea5532b83a56bbbae2fffc80de4fee.png" ><img src="http://52.1.47.143/file/attachment/2015/03/a4ea5532b83a56bbbae2fffc80de4fee.png" height="150px" width="150px" /></a><a class="comment_attach_image_link_dwl"  href="http://52.1.47.143/feed/download/year_2015/month_03/file_a4ea5532b83a56bbbae2fffc80de4fee.png" >Download</a></div>'
)           
);

$newArray = array();
foreach($comments as $comment) {
    $text = strstr($comment['text'], '<div');
    if (strlen($text) <= 0) {
        $newArray[] = array(
            'type' => 'text',
            'url' => '',
            'text' => $comment['text']
        );
    } else if($xml = @simplexml_load_string($text)) {
        $newArray[] = array(
            'type' => substr(strrchr($xml['class'], '_'), 1),
            'url' => $xml->a['href']->asXML(),
            'text' => strtok($comment['text'], '<')
        );
    } else {
        continue;
    };
}

var_dump($newArray);
```

Output:

```
array (size=9)
0 => 
array (size=3)
  'type' => string 'text' (length=4)
  'url' => string '' (length=0)
  'text' => string 'Second Comment Added' (length=20)
1 => 
array (size=3)
  'type' => string 'text' (length=4)
  'url' => string '' (length=0)
  'text' => string 'This is the long comment added to check thwe size of the comment on the device,if the size is more then add the hyperlink button to go on to the next page' (length=154)
2 => 
array (size=3)
  'type' => string 'text' (length=4)
  'url' => string '' (length=0)
  'text' => string 'This comment is of two lines need to check more about it' (length=56)
3 => 
array (size=3)
  'type' => string 'text' (length=4)
  'url' => string '' (length=0)
  'text' => string 'This comment is of two lines need to check more ' (length=48)
4 => 
array (size=3)
  'type' => string 'text' (length=4)
  'url' => string '' (length=0)
  'text' => string 'test' (length=4)
5 => 
array (size=3)
  'type' => string 'image' (length=5)
  'url' => string ' href="http://52.1.47.143/file/attachment/2015/03/e55f0f3080eb9828270a7963648a5826.jpeg"' (length=88)
  'text' => string '' (length=0)
6 => 
array (size=3)
  'type' => string 'file' (length=4)
  'url' => string ' href="http://52.1.47.143/feed/download/year_2015/month_03/file_1b87d4420c693f2bbdf738cbf2457d89.pdf"' (length=101)
  'text' => string '' (length=0)
7 => 
array (size=3)
  'type' => string 'text' (length=4)
  'url' => string '' (length=0)
  'text' => string 'Just did it...' (length=14)
8 => 
array (size=3)
  'type' => string 'image' (length=5)
  'url' => string ' href="http://52.1.47.143/file/attachment/2015/03/a4ea5532b83a56bbbae2fffc80de4fee.png"' (length=87)
  'text' => string '' (length=0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but can you just improve your code please? Since I'm getting everywhere null if the [text] key doesn't contain HTML code which should not happen. Wherever the comment type is image or file in key [url] one more array is being generated. It should also not happen the key [url] should only contain the respective url. Can you please do these changes to your code so that I can accept your answer? Thanks once again for your help.

Comment: Ok I recreated the entire array above so that I could test this. On key 4 in the array your <a> tag has two title attributes and it chokes because that's invalid XML. Updated code to handle weird HTML like this just in case it cant parse it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your immense help. But one last change I need in the output array. Let me add the complete required array to my question body. I'm adding within five minutes. So change your code accordingly to generate the desired output array. Thanks once again bro.

Comment: But it's skipping 9th element and in elements [5], [6] and [8] the [text] is coming blank.  Just resolve this small issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72810/discussion-between-aronkerr-and-user2839497).

Comment: Text elements added. It is skipping the filepicker.io due to the invalid duplicate title attribute as mentioned earlier. It will skip invalid HTML. Remove the extra attribute and it will work.

Comment: Still it's skipping many elements. Can you please correct your code to avoid this?

Comment: I can't make it parse invalid XML. If you have bad data you will need to extract with regex as opposed to simplexml.

Comment: So can you please provide the regex solution as an alternate way to achieve this?